# how to force list items to go to differents rows?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, web

I want to use this

the problem is thjat the list items are on the same rows. how can i put each item on the following row to make a vertical list with image at the beginning of each row  ?

```
<ul id="services-list">
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.google.com" class="image"></a>
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Header</h3>
      <p>text goes here</p>
    </div>
  </li> 
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.google.com" class="image"></a>
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Header</h3>
      <p>text goes here</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
/*a little bit of reset*/
#services-list, #services-list p, #services-list h3 {
  list-style: none;
  margin:0; padding:0;
}    
#services-list > li {
  float:left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 130px;
}    
#services-list > li > .image {
  display:block;
  float:left;
  margin-right:10px;
}

/*
this instructions are to force the dimensions of image and its container <a>
*/
#services-list > li > .image,
#services-list > li > .image > img {
  width:24px; height:24px;
}
```

Comment: above link is not open please improve it

Comment: The full content of your question must be in your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `&lt;&gt;` toolbar button) to make it runnable ([here's how to create one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: if you removed float: left from the lis it would be vertical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove float left from the below css, and you're done...

```
#services-list > li{
  float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The example is floating the lists so that it goes side by side using CSS.

```
<style>
    li { float: left; list-style: none; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add width as 100% to li items

```
#services-list > li {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your code this works:

```
li{
  list-style: none !important;
  float: left !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

see here https://codepen.io/agamj474/pen/zJmrde